# PHP round decimals

Tags: php, rounding

Is it possible to round a decimals to the nearest .5 with PHP like this:

```
number | round
----------------
 1.29  |  1.50
 2.03  |  2.00
 1.43  |  1.50
 1.13  |  1.00
11.38  | 11.50
```

I tried with:

```
$rnd= round($number,2);
```

but I get decimals like the one in the column "number" above.

Comment: Wait, which column is the input and which is the output?

Comment: Your result is rounding to the nearest hundredth like you stated.  But you didn't mean what you said.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
function round_to_nearest_half($number) {
    return round($number * 2) / 2;
}
```

Comment: What is the $f?  And you don't need the precision if it is 0.

Comment: function round_to_nearest_half($original){return (round($original * 2) / 2);}
Would be more like it !

Comment: @plor yeah, I changed my mind about the variable name half-way. ANd yes, you're right, you don't need the second argument, I just picked the syntax the OP used.

Comment: @Artefacto I knew what you were saying, and I probably should have asked "What the $f?".

Comment: If you change it to `function round_to_nearest_half($number)` or `return round($f * 2, 0) / 2;` it might actually work :p.

Answer (score -2):

You **don't want write any function** for this php round function **already have the option**, in mode is a third argument of round function. for more reference [**PHP Round Function**](http://gleegrid.com/blog/php-round-function/)

Comment: No, it does not have. Third argument in round() function determines how this function should round halves.
`round(1.5, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP); //2`  
`round(1.5, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN); //1`  
`round(1.5, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_EVEN); //2`  
`round(1.5, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_ODD); //1`  
`round(1.55, 1, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP); //1.6`  
`round(1.55, 1, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN); //1.5`  
`round(1.55, 1, PHP_ROUND_HALF_EVEN); //1.6`  
`round(1.55, 1, PHP_ROUND_HALF_ODD); //1.5`