# Round DOWN to nearest half integer in PHP

Tags: php

I need a PHP function that will take a float and round it **down to the nearest half** (x.0 or x.5). I found other functions that will round to the nearest fraction, but they round both ways.

The function I need can only round down.

#### Examples

7.778 -> 7.5

7.501 -> 7.5

7.49 -> 7.0

7.1 -> 7.0

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP round decimals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094173/php-round-decimals)

Comment: @Artefacto - not a duplicate, that question says nearest (which may be higher), this question says nearest lower or equal (i.e. only ever go down).

Answer (score 109, accepted):

```
$x = floor($x * 2) / 2;
```

Comment: I can add that you also can use ceil and round depending on how the integer should be rounded.

Comment: does this work? won't ieee754 problems break this? for example, what happens if you pass the expression 25/4 to a function that does this? Mathematically, you should get 6.5. By IEEE754 will give you 6 instead.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn this answer will give you 6 and not 6.5. I swapped `floor` out for `round` and seemed to get satisfactory results.

Answer (score 13):

A easy solution is to use modulo operator (`fmod()` function), like this :

```
function roundDown($number, $nearest){
    return $number - fmod($number, $nearest);
}

var_dump(roundDown(7.778, 0.5));
var_dump(roundDown(7.501, 0.5));
var_dump(roundDown(7.49, 0.5));
var_dump(roundDown(7.1, 0.5));
```

And the result :

[image]

The advantage it's that work with any nearest number (0.75, 22.5, 3.14 ...)

You can use the same operator to roundUp :

```
function roundUp($number, $nearest){
    return $number + ($nearest - fmod($number, $nearest));
}

var_dump(roundUp(7.778, 0.5));
var_dump(roundUp(7.501, 0.5));
var_dump(roundUp(7.49, 0.5));
var_dump(roundUp(7.1, 0.5));
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

I'm assuming PHP has a floor function: `floor($num * 2) / 2` ought to do it.

Answer (score 7):

You can do it on that way `round($number / 5, 1) * 5` the second parameter in the `round()` is the precision.

Example with `$number` equal to 4.6, 4.8 and 4.75

```
>>> round(4.6 / 5, 1) * 5;
=> 4.5
>>> round(4.8 / 5, 1) * 5;
=> 5.0
>>> round(4.75 / 5, 1) * 5;
=> 5.0
```

If you want you can `round()` down too like `round($number, 1, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN)` check the documentation for more information https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

Answer (score 3):

```
echo round($val*2) / 2;    // Done
```

Comment: Wrong, because the OP only wants to round down.

Answer (score 0):

From my job's requirements. I put an function to do this. Hope you can view it as a reference:

```
function round_half_five($no) {

    $no = strval($no);
    $no = explode('.', $no);
    $decimal = floatval('0.'.substr($no[1],0,2)); // cut only 2 number
    if($decimal > 0) {
        if($decimal <= 0.5) {
            return floatval($no[0]) + 0.5;
        } elseif($decimal > 0.5 && $decimal <= 0.99) {
            return floatval($no[0]) + 1;
        }
    } else {
        return floatval($no);
    }

}
```

Comment: Converting a number to a string to calculate is really awkward

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for integer input.

tests: 124->100, 125->150, 126->150, 187->200, 974->950, 975->1000, 980->1000

```
function roundHalf($num) {
    $rounded = round($num / 50) * 50;
    return ($num - $rounded <= 25) ? $rounded : $rounded + 50;
}
```