# PHP wrong round precision

Tags: php, decimal, rounding

**Hi !**

I've been trying to round a number with PHP but I got a precision error.

```
$test = 53.974999994;
echo round($test, 2);
```

The result I want is 53.98.

But this code gives me 53.97.

Can somebody tell me why ?

Thanks !

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you think that result is wrong?

Comment: When we round 53.974999994, aren't we supposed to get 53.98 since it becomes 53.975 (with the 9 behind) and so it should be 53.98 ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP round decimals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094173/php-round-decimals)

Comment: That's a two-step process there. It looks at the next digit (in this case 4) and asks if it's 5 or above. The answer is no so it stays as `53.97`

Comment: @hppycoder Thanks for your answers, but why does it look left to right ? Because we want to check right to left to check to last digit ?

Comment: @MarkusZeller it didn't really help, but thank you for answering

Comment: This rounding numbers sheet should help explain - https://www.factmonster.com/math-science/mathematics/rounding-numbers-rules-examples-for-fractions-sums

Comment: @hppycoder So you're telling that every number after the first 4 is ignored ?

Comment: Yes, it's ignored, because that's how math works. `53.974999994` is *less* than `53.975` and is therefore rounded down.

Comment: @El_Vanja Ok then, I learned something. I always thought when rounding numbers we went from right to left. Thanks.

Comment: Nope, you only check the next significant digit (so, if rounding to two places, you look at the third). So, in this case of rounding half-up (the default algorithm), this is the expected result.

Comment: I think you have to think of the possible computational requirements of lets say rounding Pi to 12 places. If you took all million-billion-gazzilion decimal places into account while doing that rounding You would definitely be able to fit a Quick trip to Alpha Centori into the required time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess the code is working fine, but the result you are looking for is different, if you wanna round a number to hundredths, you have to take the third decimal on the number, for example: 53.974


So, the new number it's going to be 53.97 because the third decimal doesnt allow you to aproximate the number to 53.98

[take a look](https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/math/roundingnumbers.php)

If you want to do something like:
the decimal n approximates the decimal n-1 and so on.

you can try something like this

`

```
$test = 53.974999994;

function round_with_n_decimals($number, $decimals, $decimals_to_count){
    while($decimals_to_count >= $decimals){
        $number = round($number, $decimals_to_count);
        $decimals_to_count--;
    }
    return $number;
}

echo round_with_n_decimals($test, 2, 3);
```

`

Comment: Ok, I understand the problem here, but isn't the php rounding method kinda broken then ? Because your function should the basic process of roundind a number with decimals.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this:

```
$test = 53.974999994;
echo round(round($test, 3), 2);
```

Explanation:

According to the person asking the question, what is important is actually the first two digits after the point, and in this case, rounding it as if it were 3 digits first, and then dropping it to 2 digits, the desired was achieved.

`round($test, 3)` is equal to `53.985` and `round(53.985, 2)` will give `53.99`

Comment: I tried this one and it seems to work, can you explain me how ? And is it compatible with every number ?

Comment: Gets the results the OP _thinks_ they want, but thats not necessarily the right answer

Comment: @RiggsFolly That's right, if I come with 53.94449999994 and apply your method with rounding to 3, I get 53.94 which is wrong because I want to get 53.95.

Comment: @AntoineJoublin If you can spare the time https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding

Answer (score 0):

Got your pain there.

I think I've got a more streamlined solution that automatically takes all available decimal points into account (unless you constrain it with the third variable):

```
 public function round(
    float $val,
    ? int $decimalPrecision = 2,
    ? int $maxDecimalPoints = null,
) {
    $returnValue = $val;

    $dotDividedArray = explode(".", strval($val));
    if (count($dotDividedArray) < 2) {
        return $returnValue;
    }

    $decimalPointsCount = $maxDecimalPoints ? min(strlen($dotDividedArray[1]), $maxDecimalPoints) : strlen($dotDividedArray[1]);

    if ($decimalPointsCount <= $decimalPrecision) {
        return $returnValue;
    }

    for ($i = $decimalPointsCount; $i > $decimalPrecision; $i--) {
        $returnValue = round($returnValue, $i - 1);
    }

    return $returnValue;
}
```